# Proper way of showing/hiding map overlays

Tags: iphone, dictionary, overlay

I have a custom overlay that trace the user location changes. I want to show/hide the overlay. What's the proper way of doing that?

I'm using hidden property of overlay view to show/hide it right now, but it doesn't work very well. When i pan and zoom on the map i see bits and pieces of overlay (even when i've set hidden property to TRUE).

Comment: Its always good to show the relevant code you are having problems with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of showing/hiding the overlay, i ended up adding/removing the overlay which seems to be working fine (in most cases).